# How to iterate through instances of a prototype "class" JS

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

I want a "for" or "while" loop to iterate through all the instances/objects in the prototyp/"class".
like "hasNext()" in array.

Then I wanna implement a function. for instance alertname("obj") this will then return the name of obj. the problem is that I dont know the specific obj. the function only gets a string and then it'll search in the prototypes which one is the right one.

```
   function Product(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

Product.prototype.getid = function() {
    i = this.id;
    return i;
};
Product.prototype.getname = function() {
    i = this.name;
    return i;
};

balloon = new Product(0, "Balloon");
var text = "balloon";

//doesnt work
function getname(obj) {
    i = Product.prototype.getname(obj);
    window.alert(i);
}
getname(text);
```

Comment: NB: `hasNext` does not exist in JS; you maybe thought of Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep track of all the objects you create with `new Product`. This is something you need to implement yourself.

Just create an array:

```
const stock = [];
stock.push(new Product(0, "Balloon"));
// ...
stock.push(new Product(0, "Monopoly"));
```

Then you can simply iterate them:

```
for (const product of stock) {
    console.log(product.getname());
}
```

It is for a good reason that JS does not provide you with such an array out-of-the-box: if that were done, then none of the created objects could ever be garbage-collected; they will always be regarded as something you still need to use. So it is a good thing that there is no built-in mechanism for this.

#### Concerning your own attempt

```
Product.prototype.getname(obj);
```

This does not make sense: `getname` does not take an argument. You usually call prototype functions like methods:

```
obj.getname()
```

In some cases you would want to use `Product.prototype.getname`, but that is only needed when `obj` is not an instance of `Product`, but is so similar that it would work to call `getname` on it. In that case use `.call()`:

```
Product.prototype.getname.call(obj);
```

Comment: this part doesnt work: for (const product of stock) {
    console.log(product.getname());
} the 1st error is; that no "of" in "for" loop allowed. 2nd i changed it to "in" and then it says that getname() is not a function:     for (const product in stock) {
        window.alert(product.getname());
    }

Comment: ok i converted this to a normal for loop: 
    for (var i = 0; i < stock.length;i++) {
        a =  stock[i].getname();
        window.alert(a);
    } ... now it works... thx

Comment: The [`for...of` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility) was introduced in ES2015, so it has been around for quite a while. All browsers except IE support it. What environment are you running on?

Comment: Also, using `alert` for debugging purposes is really "not done". Use `console.log` instead. The console offers nice ways to inspect your code and variables and monitor execution.